# Boilerpipe import error in python

Tags: python, boilerpipe

I have successfully installed Boilerpipe and Jpype in python but getting error while Importing boilerpipe

```
>>> import boilerpipe

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import boilerpipe
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boilerpipe\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % os.pathsep.join(jars))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype1-0.6.0-py2.7-win32.egg\jpype\_core.py", line 50, in startJVM
_jpype.startup(jvm, tuple(args), True)
RuntimeError: Unknown Exception
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your java work? Because it looks like your java is broken.

Comment: i just installed boilerplate on my computer and it all worked well. i'm running on windows and python 2.7

Comment: Yes my Java works perfectly without any error...

Comment: installing boilerplate didn't work , the error still exists